# How to filter language field in Dynamics AX?

Tags: axapta, x++, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-ax-2012

I'm trying to filter the table by the field "LanguageId" to show only "fr".
I made a new method in my form datasource
Here is my code

```
    public void filtr()
{
    DirPartyTable _dirPartyTable;
    select LanguageId from _dirPartytable
       where _dirPartyTable.LanguageId == "fr";
}
```

When running this code nothing happens.
How to invoke it to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can overwrite the init method of the DirPartyTable datasource and add this code to add a range on languageId with value "fr":

```
SysQuery::findOrCreateRange(this.query().dataSourceTable(tableNum(DirPartyTable)), fieldNum(DirPartyTable, LanguageId)).value("fr");
```